# Install Ubuntu on existing partition

Tags: system-installation

Due to an unfortunate chain of events, i have accidentally overridden ca. 10 KiB of my laptops hard drive, rendering at least my MBR and probably my Ubuntu bootsector useless (first partition; testdisk says it isn't bootable). I could luckily restore the entire partition structure with Gparted and testdisk.

Now, since my first partition is probably unusable for anything but booting, but the folder structure and files are still intact, i wondered: Can I just install Ubuntu in this partition without overriding my user files, or does the installation need to format the whole partition?

Thank you in advance,
Celina

Comment: Yes, you can. Choose "something else" and select all the required and already existing partitions (according to you) but do not tick format. This will keep all your user data and settings but any user installed software will need to be reinstalled. However this is probably not the best approach. This https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair (2nd option, install and use in a live session, internet access required) may or may not work but certainly easier to try instead of a risky reinstallation.

Comment: Probably better to just run a live session, backup everything you need and install afresh.

Comment: Thank you both! I don't have much of importance on the drive, so i guess I'll try the reinstall.